# Trouble in driving Point Grey Grasshoper cameras

Tags: camera, hardware, hardware-interface, firewire

I am trying to drive two Grasshopper cameras, from Point Grey Research, using a laptop. As my laptop (and generally majority laptop's) does not have any FireWire 800 port, I am using a FireWire 800 to Express Card device which contains two FireWire 800 ports.

I am trying to capture sample images using the example codes provided by FlyCapture (SDK of Point Grey). When I run these examples on my laptop, they show an error "Error starting isochronous stream". However, I am able to run the same examples on a desktop and could capture images successfully.

Please note that power supply to drive the cameras doesnot seem to be a problem as both the cameras show a glowing led.

I have also written a sample code using libdc1394 library to list the active cameras connected to the machine. And upon running this code on my laptop, it shows that two cameras are connected. (which may mean that the problem lie in flycapture)

Did anyone face a similar problem ? Or could any of you successfully drive one or two  Grasshopper camera using a laptop ?

Thanks a lot for the incoming help.

Answer (score 3):

This is Nina from Point Grey's Support team. I can assist you with your question.

The fact that the cameras work well on your desktop PC but generate Isochronous stream error on your laptop indicates the cameras are working well. I suspect that you are running into problems with the bandwidth when you run two camera synchronously through the express card on your laptop. As the bandwidth the express card can sustain is S800 if you try to run two grasshoppers at full frame rate and resolution you might be generating more data from the cameras than the express card can sustain. Please try reducing the frame rate or resolution on your two cameras or try running one camera only and let me know if it streams well.

What FlyCapture example code are you trying to run? Which grasshopper model are you using? When you tested the camera on your PC did you run the cameras on two separate firewire buses?

Please let me know. You can also contact us by sending us an email at support@ptgrey.com

Regards,
Nina

Comment: Hi Nina, Thanks a lot for the immediate reply. I have sent an email to support@ptgrey.com
regards,